# Creating a new column of string values that is assigned based on numerical row value in another column of CSV in Pandas returns error: "KeyError: 0"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Using Pandas in Python, importing and exporting CSV files.

The datatype in the column of Type, is imported into a dataframe with the datatype int64 from the original CSV.

Trying to achieve it so based on the numerical value in column named Type of the original CSV, a corresponding type (textstring) will be added to a column Newtype.  This lookup will happen using a dictionary in the following manner:

If the Type is equal to 1, this "row" from the CSV will be assigned the textstring "NameOne" in same row in the column (named Newtype) next to it in the CSV that is exported (at the end of the code.)

```
import pandas as pd

import csv



df = pd.read_csv("import.csv", names=["A", "B", "Month", "Day", "Time", "Type"])


df['Newtype'] = df['Type']

dictio = {1:'NameOne', 2:'NameTwo', 3:'NameThree', 4:'NameFour', 5:'NameFive'}


df['Newtype'] = df['Newtype'].apply(lambda x: dictio[x])


df.to_csv("export.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

However an error is returned when running this code, and the error is:

```
KeyError: 0
```

The above error is returned for the following line in the code:

```
df['Newtype'] = df['Newtype'].apply(lambda x: dictio[x])
```

I suspect that the problematic line of code would be the following, but I can't see how I should modify it correctly, any suggestions?

```
df['Newtype'] = df['Type']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dict which you named it as dictio, then we just need `map` here (Or `replace`)

```
df['Newtype'] = df['Type'].map(dictio)
#df['Newtype'] = df['Type'].replace(dictio)
```